# How to add multiple markers on the google map

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying add multiple markers from the coordinates read from the firebase. It reads all the coordinates and store in the list. I have created the addMarker function to add the markers to the map. But it only prints a one marker, the last marker coordinates read. Can anyone help me to resolve this as I am new to flutter.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final textcontroller = TextEditingController();
  final databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};

  double latitude = 0;
  double longitude = 0;
  var myList = [];
  List<LatLng> list = [];

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      firebaseRead();
    });
  }

  void firebaseRead() {
    databaseRef.child('Locations').onValue.listen((Event event) {
      myList = event.snapshot.value;

      setState(() {
        for (int x = 0; x < myList.length; x++) {
          double latitude = myList[x]['lat'];
          double longitude = myList[x]['long'];
          LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
          if (list.contains(location)) {
            list.clear();
            list.add(location);
          } else {
            list.add(location);
          }

          addMarker(list[x]);
        }
      });

    });
    //print(list);
  }

  void addMarker(loc) {
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId('Marker 1');

    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: LatLng(loc.latitude, loc.longitude),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'test'),
    );

    setState(() {
      // adding a new marker to map
      markers[markerId] = marker;
      //print(marker);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Firebase Demo"),
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        markers: Set.of(markers.values),
        initialCameraPosition:
            CameraPosition(target: LatLng(6.9271, 79.8612), zoom: 15),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          firebaseRead();
        },
        label: const Text('Refresh'),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is because you have only one `MarkerId` so after calling `markers[markerId] = marker;` the map `markers` will always have one item

Comment: Can you please tell me the way to add markerId for ll the coordinate points.

Comment: `final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(loc.toString());` maybe? (assuming that `loc.toString()` returns valid unique `String`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always using a single `markerId` which means you're overwriting the previous marker with the next marker and which is why there's always only one.

For dynamic marker's list, you've to pass a dynamic `markerId`. See, the modified code below:

```
void firebaseRead() {
    databaseRef.child('Locations').onValue.listen((Event event) {
        myList = event.snapshot.value;
        setState(() {
            for (int x = 0; x < myList.length; x++) {
              double latitude = myList[x]['lat'];
              double longitude = myList[x]['long'];
              LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
              if (list.contains(location)) {
                 list.clear();
                  list.add(location);
              } else {
                  list.add(location);
              }

              //Passing a dynamic marker id as the index here.
              addMarker(list[x], x);
            }
        });
    });
    //print(list);
}

//Adding Index here as an argument
void addMarker(loc, index) {
    //Making this markerId dynamic
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId('Marker $index');

    final Marker marker = Marker(
       markerId: markerId,
       position: LatLng(loc.latitude, loc.longitude),
       infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'test'),
    );

    setState(() {
      // adding a new marker to map
      markers[markerId] = marker;
      //print(marker);
    });
}
```

In this code, the change is `index` is taken from the for loop and passed to the `markerId`, so now, the `markerId` will be different for each marker passed from the `firebaseRead()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.30` this version You can do something like **this**:-

```
List<Marker> _markers = <Marker>[];

for(var track in myList){
        if(track["latitude"] != "" && track["latitude"] != "null"){
          _markers.add(Marker(markerId: MarkerId(myList.indexOf(track).toString()),
              position: LatLng(double.parse(track["latitude"]), double.parse(track["longitude"])),
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: track["Name"])));
        }
      }
      
      
      GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: latitude == null && longitude == null
                  ? LatLng(23.022505, 72.571365)
                  : LatLng(latitude, longitude)),
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
        )
```