# Cannot add more than one marker in google map (flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-maps-markers

I am trying to add multiple markers in google map but once I call the function, only the last marker is shown. What am I missing?

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189503/how-to-add-multiple-markers-on-the-google-map) that I must pass a dynamic markerId, which I think I am already doing but for some reason I cannot get the first marker, always the last one.

Note: It's not a typo type of issue - if I remove the `last` marker, the `first` marker is being displayed. So it must have something to do with the function overwriting the `first` marker with the `last` one:

```
  void Markers() async {
    var firstPath = "img/first.png";
    final Uint8List firstIcon = await getBytesFromAsset(firstPath, 50);
    var lastPath = "img/last.png";
    final Uint8List lastIcon = await getBytesFromAsset(lastPath, 50);

    _listmarkers = Set<Marker>();
    _listmarkers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(_navigationList.first.userId.toString()),
      position: LatLng(_navigationList.first.latitude,
          _navigationList.first.longitude),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(firstIcon),
    ));

    _listmarkers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(_navigationList.last.userId.toString()),
      position: LatLng(_navigationList.last.latitude,
          _navigationList.last.longitude),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(lastIcon),
    ));
    setState(() {});
  }

  void createMap() {
    if (_navigationList.isNotEmpty) {
      _postsController.add(1);
      LatLngBounds bound = boundsFromLatLngList(_navigationList);
      Markers();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably

```
_navigationList.last.userId.toString() == _navigationList.first.userId.toString()
```

Comment: unfortunately, it's not that. If I remove the `last` marker, the `first` one is shown and they have different point on the map.

Comment: How that disproves what I just wrote? IMO both have the same ID. Position has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I have the understanding that `first` and `last` get the element value. In my case, the values of the elements are the latitude and longitude coordinates, which are different. Hence, the different points on the map.  Here is how I get the list element values: `_navigationList.addAll(value),
                  value.forEach((element) { polylineCoordinates
                        .add(LatLng(element.latitude, element.longitude)); }),`

Comment: You are missing the point.

Comment: Yes indeed, I might be missing the point. May I ask you to please explain because my logic is probably wrong? if `_navigationList.last.userId.toString() == _navigationList.first.userId.toString()`, this would mean that `.first` == `.last`. How would the values of `first` and `last` be the same if when building the list those elements have different coordinates, therefore different values?

Comment: im saying that both elements contains the same userId. Just verify that and let us know what is the conclusion

Comment: Yes, it's the same `user.Id`. Those coordinates are all for one and the same user. But isn't enough that the values of `first` and `last` are different? Or should I add another element identifier like `coordinateId`, i.e. `_navigationList.first.userId.coordinateId.toString()`?

Comment: but it is your MARKER ID therfore you are duplicating the ids, thus the result. Make marker ID unique and it will work.

Comment: yes, you are correct. setting a unique value for the `MarkerId` like `markerId: MarkerId("first"),` and `markerId: MarkerId("last"),` worked. I still don't understand why setting `.first` and `.last` in the marker id doesn't make it uniquely but I will do some more investigation to better understand the logic. Thank you for the patience, indeed helped me to resolve the problem!

Comment: because `first` and `last` item contains THE SAME ID.